# Impresspages language settings in backend

Tags: impresspages

I can't switch language into German. I've done this:
Translate CMS core

ImpressPages tries to download required translations when you install new language. Full list of languages with available translations can be found on Transifex website. These translations are made by our community. You can help too and add some translations.

If default translations are missing in your language or you don't like the default ones, you can add your own translations. Just create a JSON file  in files/translations/override directory with required translations. The JSON file uses the same syntax as described in plugin and theme translation cases above. Use Ip-admin-fr.json for administration page translations, and Ip-fr.json for other web site texts (here fr is two character language code). For plugin translations, use your plugin name.
- See more at: http://www.impresspages.org/docs/translations#sthash.nGTMB2um.dpuf

The language in backend is already english. What's to do?

Answer (score 1):

Download https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/impresspages/resource/ip-admin/ German translation and put it as file/translations/original/Ip-admin-de.json

Add `'adminLocale' => 'de'` in config.php:

```
return array(
    'adminLocale' => 'de',
    'sessionName' => 'ses1477701042', // prevents session conflict when two sites runs on the same server
    'developmentEnvironment' => 0, // displays error and debug information. Change to 0 before deployment to production server
    'showErrors' => 1, // 0 if you don't wish to display errors on the page
    ...
    ...
    ...
);
```

We will make this process easier in future releases.

Comment: Do you mean config.php in root? This does not work at my installation. I get a blank site at frontend and backend…
I've tested these strings at config.php: "adminLocale" => "de" and 'adminLocale' => 'de'
Both won't work.

Comment: Yes, config.php in the root. I have updated asnwer and updated example.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've got forgotten the comma in the string … my fault, no it works.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a new language, you actually add new language for the frontend not the backend. There is no graphich interface to change admin language yet. But you can take translations from https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/impresspages/ and put in the right place as described here in the last paragraph http://www.impresspages.org/docs/translations.

Comment: Well, that's what I made. I've downloaded for_use_impresspages_Install_de.json, renamed it in ip-admin_de.json and copied it at /file/translations/override. But language in backend is already in english …

Comment: It looks like you have downloaded just installation translations. This process is not so straight forward yet. There are many points you can make a mistake. I will ask for Algimantas to support you. He is our internationalization guru :)

Answer (score 0):

Please read on ImpressPages documentation: http://www.impresspages.org/docs/translations

Section "Admin interface translations".